# How RecommenderJob(org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob) will call my custom mappers and reducers?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am running Mahout in Action example for 6 using command:

"hadoop jar target/mia-0.1-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=input/input.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=output --usersFile input/users.txt --booleanData"

But the mappers and reducers in example of ch 06 are not working ?

Comment: what is not working, and what does it have to do with custom implementations?

Comment: Sorry, If I am not clear. The mappers and reducers mentioned in example like WikipediaToItemPrefsMapper, WikipediaToUserVectorReducer, UserVectorToCooccurrenceMapper, UserVectorToCooccurrenceReducer, etc are not executed at all instead it uses the existing mappers and reducers provided in RecommenderJob. I need to know what needs to be done inorder to call the custom mappers and reducers via org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code to use the custom `Mapper` and `Reducer` classes you have in mind. Otherwise yes of course it runs the ones that are currently in the code. Add them, change the caller, recompile, and run it all on Hadoop. I am not sure what you refer to that is not working.

Comment: Thanks Sean, so either I will have to override the class org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob or create new caller/driver class for calling my mappers and reducers.